# Where is the .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess

I have just installed a Drupal 8 website using `drush dl drupal-8 --select`.
I have rewrite issues because there is no `.htaccess` in my root directory.

Where can I find the default `.htaccess` file for Drupal 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you download Drupal from [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/8.3.0), there is the .htaccess file in main directory.

How do you downloaded Drupal source code?

Comment: I used drush command `drush dl drupal-8 --select`. I will try from the link you provided.

Comment: Or simply get only the .htaccess file

Comment: Look at the vendor directory: there is an .htaccess also there.

Answer (score 2):

I executed the command you quoted, and I got the following files. (I executed `ls -alF` in the directory where Drupal 8.3.0 was copied from Drush.)

> -rw-rw-rw- 1 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno    262 Apr  6 02:12 autoload.php
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno   2309 Apr  6 02:12 composer.json
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno 152480 Apr  6 02:12 composer.lock
>    drwxrwxrwx 0 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno      0 Apr  6 02:12 core/
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno   1025 Apr  6 02:12 .csslintrc
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno    350 Apr  6 02:12 .editorconfig
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno    206 Apr  6 02:12 .eslintignore
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno     41 Apr  6 02:12 .eslintrc.json
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno   1346 Apr  6 02:12 example.gitignore
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno   3671 Apr  6 02:12 .gitattributes
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno   7866 Apr  6 02:12 .htaccess
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno    549 Apr  6 02:12 index.php
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno  18092 Nov 17 00:57 LICENSE.txt
>    drwxrwxrwx 0 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno      0 Apr  6 02:12 modules/
>   drwxrwxrwx 0 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno      0 Apr  6 02:12 profiles/
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno   5889 Apr  6 02:12 README.txt
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno   1596 Apr  6 02:12 robots.txt
>    drwxrwxrwx 0 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno      0 Apr  6 02:12 sites/
>   drwxrwxrwx 0 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno      0 Apr  6 02:12 themes/
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno    848 Apr  6 02:12 update.php
>    drwxrwxrwx 0 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno      0 Apr  6 02:38 vendor/
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno   4555 Apr  6 02:12 web.config

If you don't see .htaccess it is because files starting with a dot are normally considered hidden, and the CLI doesn't normally show those files, except when telling the command to show all the files.

Alternatively, you could run `composer create-project drupal/drupal your_site_directory 8.3.*@dev --no-dev` if you have Composer installed, which copies the following files/directories.

> -rw-rw-rw- 1 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno    262 Apr 14 11:34 autoload.php
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno   2247 Apr 14 11:34 composer.json
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno 152480 Apr 14 11:34 composer.lock
>   drwxrwxrwx 0 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno      0 Apr 14 11:35 core/
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno   1025 Apr 14 11:34 .csslintrc
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno    350 Apr 14 11:34 .editorconfig
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno    206 Apr 14 11:34 .eslintignore
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno     41 Apr 14 11:34 .eslintrc.json
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno   1346 Apr 14 11:35 example.gitignore
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno   3671 Apr 14 11:34 .gitattributes
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno   7866 Apr 14 11:34 .htaccess
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno    549 Apr 14 11:35 index.php
>   drwxrwxrwx 0 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno      0 Apr 14 11:35 modules/
>   drwxrwxrwx 0 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno      0 Apr 14 11:35 profiles/
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno   5889 Apr 14 11:34 README.txt
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno   1596 Apr 14 11:35 robots.txt
>   drwxrwxrwx 0 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno      0 Apr 14 11:35 sites/
>   drwxrwxrwx 0 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno      0 Apr 14 11:35 themes/
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno    848 Apr 14 11:35 update.php
>   drwxrwxrwx 0 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno      0 Apr 14 11:36 vendor/
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 kiamlaluno kiamlaluno   4555 Apr 14 11:35 web.config

In both the cases, the .htaccess file is copied.